# How to delete Non-Group connected SharePoint sites via PowerAutomate, using the SharePoint API

Tags: rest, sharepoint, power-automate

I have a super simple flow that is manually triggered. The objective of the flow is to delete a Non-Group Connected SharePoint site. I have used the official Microsoft documentation on how to use the REST API, but I keep getting Error 400, bad request errors every time I run the flow when trying to send an http request. I have attached a photo to show the step involved. All of the code, as far as I'm aware, is exactly as the documentation states. but I cannot seem to get the step to complete successfully. There seems to be lots of people having success with group connected SharePoint sites, but as far as I'm aware that's a different process.

NOTE: For the Site Address input, I have tried the URL dynamic content (within screenshot), as well as manually typing the admin centre URL and also manually typing the URL of the site wanting to be deleted. None of the three work.[Screenshot of PowerAutomate Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jcrpb.png)

I have also attempted to use DELETE instead of POST, which also wasn't successful.